# BLE Beacon doesn't wake the app in background when screen is turned off

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm developing an application that communicates with a BLE device and for the purpose of the app, a Beacon (Eddystone) has been implemented in the BLE device.

In my application I implemented all the codes for Beacon recognition. Everything is working properly. When the application is `terminated`, iOS recognizes the Beacon and wakes up my application to execute code.

To verify that the code executes correctly I trigger local notifications at certain stages of the code executed by the wake up of the Beacon.

I receive all my notifications correctly and when I lock the screen and the screen turns off, it always works without problems.
Notifications are for testing only, but in the Production environment there will be no notifications.

**My Problem:**

When I'm in Production mode (without local notifications)

1. App is `terminated` & screen is locked + turned `ON` = **Code executes successfully**
2. App is `terminated` & screen is locked + turned `OFF` = **Beacon doesn't wake the app - nothing happens**

What can be the reason? Are there any limits to using the Beacon? iOS does not listen to the Beacon when the screen is off?

**NOTE:**

1. Location permission is set to `Always allow`.
2. The Beacon used is `Eddystone` and not `iBeacon` - Can it be the reason?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: iOS don't have native support for Eddystone, you don't include any relevant code or library name, not sure how anyone can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on CLbeaconRegion 's `notifyOnExit` property to true...